# jQuery regular expression to remove number which does not meet requirements

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying my best to find a solution for my regex problem but failing.
I want to replace my input with blank (real-time) when the input is not a float number.

This is what I did for the integer input.

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".onlyInteger", function(event){
if (!(event.keyCode >=37 && event.keyCode<=40)) {
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    inputVal = inputVal.replace(/[^0-9]/gi,'');

    $(this).val( addComma(inputVal) );
}
```

});

I would like to apply this code to replace non-float input with '' but could not find a **negated regex** for float number.

The result I want to get.

```
10,000 --> true
10 --> true
0.1 --> true
1.23234 --> true
1,231.123 --> true
0.000001 --> true
1.000 --> true


. at the beginning --> false (replace with blank)
0001.2 --> false (replace with blank)
-1.01 --> false (replace with blank)
+2.3 --> false (replace with blank)
characters --> false (replace with blank)
1.1.1.1 --> false (replace with blank)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why is -1.01 not a float? Are you looking for specifically positive values?

Comment: Technically speaking, 0001.2, -1.01 and +2.3 are legal floats in EcmaScript. Are you sure you want them excluded?

Comment: Notice that different locales have different formats, that may not fit your description/expectations. See [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) and [NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat).

Comment: Couple of questions.  Why are you expecting `true` for `"10,000"`, technically it's more correctly an int, not a float.  Do you have to do this with a regex?  (Sounds suspiciously like it might be an XY problem).  Are you trying to detect floating point numbers, or will any number be ok?

Comment: @Yaelet it's because I'll use the float value to indicate an area like 10.5㎥

Comment: @Tibrogargan I made it to add a comma automatically for a number so the comma should not be excluded in this case

Comment: You probably could consider changing the question title.  You're want numbers that aren't technically floats while excluding some that are.  More like "remove number which does not meet requirements"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [**regex**](https://regex101.com/r/jn1j5K/1) `^(([0-9,]+)|(([1-9,]+|0)\.\d+))$`.

```js
const regex = /^(([0-9,]+$)|(([1-9,]+|0)\.\d+))$/gm
const str = '10'
const numbers = regex.test(str) ? str : ''
console.log(numbers)
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to replace what doesn't match this regex to blank real-time. Can you let me know the negated regex for this?

Comment: @YoojinKim same way you negate any pattern.  `(?! pattern )`

Answer (score 0):

Use `^(([1-9]+0{0,})|([1-9]\d?(\,\d{3}){0,})|0)(\.\d+)?$` could fit your need.

Here's a simple test:

```js
var casesShouldPass = [
  "10,000",
  "10",
  "0.1",
  "1.23234",
  "1,231.123",
  "0.000001",
  "1.000",

  // I think the followings should pass
  "1,234,567",
  "1,234,567.00",
  "123456",
  "12345.3",
  "10.3",
  "100.4",
  "13",
  "0",
  "9",
  "1,230,333,444,555,666.2"
];

var casesShouldFail = [
  ".",
  ".123",
  "0001.2",
  "-1.01",
  "+2.3",
  "abc",
  "1.1.1.1",

  // I think the followings should fail
  "1,23",
  "1,2",
  "1,",
  "0,111",
  "0.",
  "a.0",
  "0.abc",
];

var body = document.querySelector("body");
var regex = /^(([1-9]+0{0,})|([1-9]\d?(\,\d{3}){0,})|0)(\.\d+)?$/;
var testFunc = (arr) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var result = regex.test(arr[i]);
    body.innerHTML += `${arr[i]} : ${result}<br>`;
  }
  body.innerHTML += `<br>`;
}

testFunc(casesShouldPass);
testFunc(casesShouldFail);
```

You can simply test the input value with the pattern and if it does not pass then remove the value from the input.

Also, I would suggest using `change` instead of using `keyup`, you can try it out in this snippet.

```js
var regex = /^(([1-9]+0{0,})|([1-9]\d?(\,\d{3}){0,})|0)(\.\d+)?$/;

$(document).on("keyup", ".onlyInteger_keyup", function(event) {
  if (!(event.keyCode >= 37 && event.keyCode <= 40)) {
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    if (!regex.test(inputVal)) {
      $(this).val("");
    }
  }
})


$(document).on("change", ".onlyInteger_change", function(event) {
  if (!(event.keyCode >= 37 && event.keyCode <= 40)) {
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    if (!regex.test(inputVal)) {
      $(this).val("");
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
OnKeyup
<input type="text" class="onlyInteger_keyup" />
<br> 
OnChange
<input type="text" class="onlyInteger_change" />
```